# Radius of a box in a given direction

Tags: math, language-agnostic, physics, game-physics

Let's say I have an axis-aligned box. I also have a location outside that box.

How do I get the point on the boundaries of the box that is along the line from the center of the box to that point? (And thus, know how far the box extends in that direction).

EDIT: preferably, if the point is inside the box, it should just return the point... but that's something I could easily calculate myself.

2D diagram (Though the answer will preferably work in 3D as well):

[image]

Comment: This is high school algebra. What research have you done?  What have you tried?

Comment: @Gene: You say it's extremely basic, but I'm having trouble figuring out an efficient formula for it.  The trick is that it's a ray intersecting (probably) all 6 planes, and you have to figure out which plane it is.

Comment: You can decide which face the line segment (you show a segment, not a ray) intersects just by checking dx = x2 - x1 and similarly dy and dz for both sign and comparative magnitudes.  E.g. in 2d if dx is positive and |dx| > |dy| then it intersects the right face.  The intersection point is just y = y1 + dy(x_right - x1)/dx  (P1 is the one in the center of the box.

Comment: I got this before I realized it's only right if the point is in the "positive" direction from the middle of the box on all three axis.  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9d3d7d6057efc0e2

Comment: simply comparing `dx,dy,dz` of the point to the middle only works if the bounding box is a perfect cube, which is a dubious assumption.  You'd have to relate those magnitudes to the magnitudes of a corner to the middle, and that relation is far trickier.

Comment: @MooingDuck It's not tricky. For the x face just compare the absolute slope of the line in the xy plane with the slope the diagonal of an xy-face on the cube.  Then do the same in the xz plane.  The line hits the face iff both line slopes are less than or equal to the respective diagonal slopes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
point3d getIntersection(point3d topfrontleft, point3d backbottomright, point3d externpt)
{
    //find the middle
    point3d middle(topfrontleft/2+backbottomright/2);
    //slide box and source as if the "middle" was at the origin
    topfrontleft -= middle;
    backbottomright-= middle;
    externpt-= middle;
    //scale source as if the box is the unit square
    externpt/= topfrontleft;
    //find the largest magnitude of the source offset
    point3d mag = abs(externpt);
    auto max = std::max(mag.x,std::max(mag.y,mag.z));
    //if it's inside the box, don't scale
    if (max < 1)
        max = 1;
    //scale the source so that it touches the box
    externpt/= max;
    //then scale and slide that touching point back to original coordinates
    externpt= externpt* topfrontleft + middle;
    return externpt;
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9d9504964bc650bb

I'm not experienced with 3d math, so there's probably faster and more effective ways.  No idea.
As a bonus, this algorithm doesn't make any reference to the number of dimensions except for finding the largest magnitude, so should work in both 2d, 3d, and any other theoretical number of dimensions.

Comment: My current testing is in a semi-2D environment - everything is flat, but mins.Z = -1, maxs.Z = 1 just to prevent errors. However, when I try to implement your code... source.Z is always 0, so min = 0, and then you divide by min... (also, I'm assuming source = the target point. Not sure on that.)

Comment: @mcmonkey4eva: Yeah, source=target point.  The more I think about it, the step where it "scales the source by the smallest magnitude to touch the bounding box" is entirely wrong.  I'll have to think on it some more.  Maybe it should be the largest magnitude?  I think that's it.

Comment: Yeah, now my results match those of the other answer, so that's good.

Comment: And it's now 100% accurate. No flipping, no weirdness, nothing but valid results. Awesome! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code that does what I said in comments modified for rectangular boxes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

// Find intersection p between line A->B and box. 
// Point A must be the box center.
// The box is [x_left, y_bottom, x_right, y_top].
void find_box_intersect(double *box, double *a, double *b, double *p)
{
  double dx = b[0] - a[0];
  double dy = b[1] - a[1];
  if (fabs(dx * (box[3] - box[1])) > fabs(dy * (box[2] - box[0]))) {
    p[0] = dx > 0 ? box[2] : box[0];
    p[1] = a[1] + dy * (p[0] - a[0]) / dx;
  } else {
    p[1] = dy > 0 ? box[3] : box[1];
    p[0] = a[0] + dx * (p[1] - a[1]) / dy;
  }
}

int main(void) {

  double box[] = { 1, 2, 
                   2, 4 };
  double p[2], a[] = { 0.5 * (box[0] + box[2]), 
                       0.5 * (box[1] + box[3]) };
  int i, n = 16;

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    double theta = 2 * 3.14159 * i / n;
    double b[] = { a[0] + cos(theta), a[1] + sin(theta) };
    find_box_intersect(box, a, b, p);
    printf("%.2f, %.2f\n", p[0], p[1]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The 3d generalization of this is straightforward.  Rather than the `if` statement that determines only 2 cases, there will be a 3 case if-else chain that determines 3: left-right, top-bottom, front-back.

Output:

```
2.00, 3.00
2.00, 3.21
2.00, 3.50
1.91, 4.00
1.50, 4.00
1.09, 4.00
1.00, 3.50
1.00, 3.21
1.00, 3.00
1.00, 2.79
1.00, 2.50
1.09, 2.00
1.50, 2.00
1.91, 2.00
2.00, 2.50
2.00, 2.79
```

Comment: Translating your code gets me to http://pastebin.com/6EftZdRZ which... doesn't work at all. It's just a random point vaguely near the box, consistently in the X+Y+ direction.
Also, wouldn't the abs(dx)>abs(dy) comparison only work for a perfect square?

Comment: @mcmonkey4eva Well it works just fine for me.  I changed the pseudocode to C.

Comment: @mcmonkey4eva My pseudocode assumed the box is square.  Is it?

Comment: I got it mostly working... It stays firmly within the box, along the borders, but seems to flip between pointing towards the target and opposite it. My code translation: http://pastebin.com/9EEgBwiX

Comment: @mcmonkey4eva My code is correct. Yours is un-runnable (and at any rate I don't have VS with C#), so you're going to have to fix it on your own.  I have no idea what "flip" and "target" are.

Comment: @Gene: I think he means sometimes you're finding the point where the segment touches the box, and sometimes you're finding the point where the _line_ touches the opposite side of the box.

Comment: @MooingDuck  Thanks.  You're probably right. Maybe his code does that.  Mine can't.

Comment: @mcmonkey4eva can you provide inputs that show the problem? If so we can help pin down the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Intersect the line with the (right) border of the box.

Longer answer:

- x is easy: It's at the right border of the box.
- for y, solve this: y/line_height = (line_width - box_width/2) / line_width

  then add the y of the line lower point

This is assuming the line intersects the right border, as in your picture.
To figure which border the line intersects, compare the ratio of line_height/line_width, and the signs, to the ratio of box_height/box_width.

If the box is square and you're only interested in the radius, and not the intersection point, you can throw away the signs of line_width and line_height, sort them, and just solve one case.

If the box is not square, you can still throw away the signs, but need to compare the ratios to pick one of two remaining cases (in 2D).

Comment: Trying to intersect the line with each border sounds so... brute-forcey. I was trying to avoid that.

Comment: Well, then write the calculations for all 4 sides on paper and see if you can simplify...

Comment: @mcmonkey4eva: Hardly brute force since you don't have to "guess" at any point and the math is trivial for 2d intersecting a particular face of the box.  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f5702fa5682d7dc1  However, if the box has multiple faces it gets slightly trickier.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you know the length and width of the rect, if the angle is pointing left or right, then x is known, so you only need to solve for y (r * sin(angle)); if the angle is pointing up or down, then y is known so you solve for x (r * cos(angle)).

```
// where the center of the rect = 0, 0 and angles are in degrees 0..360
// determine the 45's first
if (angle in (45, 135, 225, 315)) {
    return { x:cos(angle) * (width / 2), y:sin(angle) * (height / 2) };
}

if (angle < 45 || angle > 315) {
    // pointing right
    return { x:(width / 2), y:sin(angle) * (height / 2) };
}

if (angle > 45 && angle < 135) {
    // pointing up
    return { x:cos(angle) * (width / 2), y:(height / 2) };
}

if (angle > 135 && angle < 225) {
    // pointing left
    return { x:(width / -2), y:sin(angle) * (height / 2) };
}

if (angle > 225 && angle < 315) {
    // pointing down
    return { x:cos( angle ) * (width / 2), y:(height / -2) };
}
```

There are undoubtedly more elegant mathematical solutions to this problem, but this one works for me--understandable, testable, etc.

Comment: this is accurate on a general scale but not precise - it seems to rapidly flicker slightly off-direction in different ways from the slightest twitch in location.

Comment: @mcmonkey4eva it really shouldnt be.  Are you certain your inouts are degrees and cos/sin is in degrees? Can you provude sample inputsthat have the wrong result?